# SQLite: Update command don't change value

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have this problem.... the code below don't produce errors but the table not commit change!
I've controlled all logs, all value are correct and all If test gone fine, but the value on the db not change.
someone have an idea?
thanks!!

```
- (void) saveData {
    //database file system
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"enduroRace.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"unable to load db: '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    //apro database
    sqlite3 *db;
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"unable to open DB");
    }
    //inizio query
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    NSString *querySQL = @"UPDATE setting SET delay=?";
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        int valoreAttuale = [[sharedClass sharedController] ritardoMusic];
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1,valoreAttuale);
    }
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error...");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(db);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm understood.... I've copied the Sqlite db into 'Documents' folder that is not only read only and now is perfect!!! thanks to me !!!